# What was the change made by Spielberg to E.T.?

Tags: et-the-extra-terrestrial, steven-spielberg

Some people at work, while discussing "Han Shot First", noted that Spielberg made pretty bad changes as well, so it's not like Lucas was the only one. But nobody remembered anything specific, other than it having to do with guns.

- Was there a big change made to E.T. in later revisions by Spielberg?
- If so, what was it?

Comment: Handy to have "Han Short First" tag - thanks to whoever created!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083866/trivia):

> Steven Spielberg is reported to have spent $100,000 digitally removing guns from the 20th Anniversary re-release of the movie in 2002. He regretted using the scene and said he would remove it if he ever re-issued the film.

Yeah, Han didn't shoot first... he was carrying a napkin!

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a full list of changes, courtesy of [Snopes boards](http://msgboard.snopes.com/cgi-bin/ultimatebb.cgi?ubb=get_topic;f=75;t=000796;p=1):

1. At least one new scene is added: E.T. is seen in a bathtub filled with water, alluding to the fact that he can survive in more extreme conditions than human beings can.
2. When the mother explains to one of her kids that she doesn't want him to go out on Halloween looking like a terrorist, "terrorist" is changed to "hippie."
3. Any government officer shown mysteriously traded in his gun for a walkie-talkie. They made fun of this in an episode of South Park, and for good reason.

   Nothing says "peculiar edit" like having a bunch of Feds pointing walkie talkies at some kids and their alien.

Comment: What about the alteration of the penis-breath line...?

Comment: @TGnat - no idea what that is... make it an answer

Comment: I could be wrong.  It might have been a TV version that had that particular change: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaWUaboCIrM